# Error on JDoodle saying it can't find class name when I had made a class name

Tags: java

I wanted to make a simple dice game for Java. I used an online compiler called JDoodle. After I wrote all the code, it gave me the error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class MyClass
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyClass

Here's the code I wrote where I defined the class name:

```
package MyClass;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class MyClass
```

I've never coded Java before and I wanted to get myself introduced to it and tried making a dice game. I did what I thought had made a main class name. That's the code they used in the tutorial (except just with a different name). If you know what I did wrong, I'd appreciate the help in fixing it.

Comment: Is this in a folder called `MyClass` - which needs to match the package name?  And did you run it with `java MyClass.MyClass` - that is, the package name and the class name?  These things are far less confusing if you use a package name that's NOT the same as the class name.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I don't know about the folder, I used an online compiler. I had the class named differently and got the issue so I set it to MyClass, which was the default name, to try and fix the issue. Also I tried a similar thing to java MyClass.MyClass but it didn't work. Should I try running it with that? How and where would I fit that in?

Comment: What online compiler?  Does it come with a "run" option?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem It's called JDoodle. Basically there's a box to type in your code, below that an execute button which runs your code, then below that a a text area where code is outputted. Also, I put in `Java MyClass.MyClass` in place of the main class name, and got this error:
>/java.java:5 error:  '{' expected public class java MyClass.MyClass

Comment: And you have a method in your class that starts `public static void main(String[] args)` ?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem yes

Comment: OK, I've just been playing with JDoodle.  I can't see a way to get it to accept a package declaration.  It looks like it can only work with one file of source code at a time, and you can't arrange your classes into packages.  This is a serious limitation, I'm afraid.  So it looks like you'll have to remove the package declaration from your code.  Seriously, I wouldn't bother trying to learn Java from this - try the free version of IntelliJ or Eclipse instead, which will let you do a whole lot more.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem the only reason I used Jdoodle is I needed to show coding on a school assignment, and it's hard to download programs on the school computers because of time. I'm already this far in so I feel like I have to get it to work. What code do I need to get rid of and how can I change it to make it still work?

Comment: Just get rid of the package declaration.  The very first line of code.